# Custom cells - UICollectionView inside UITableVIew

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uicollectionview, xib

**Hi,**

I have a UICollectionView embedded inside UITableView. It looks like this tutorial: http://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell/

except! i want to have labels in each UICollectionViewCell that display their indexPath.row.

**Problem**:
I don't know how to connect to my XIB with UICollectionViewCell - since my class, called MainTableCollectionViewCell is a UITableViewCell class (not a UICollectionViewCell class). I need to be able to manipulate the label of a cell, with the @IBoutlet but it wont connect now, because i cant connect my class to XIB

**here is my project inspector:**

MainTableCollectionViewCell.xib - this is my Collection View Cell

MainTableCollectionView.xib - just an empty single view

MainTableCollectionViewCellControler.swift

MainTableCollectionViewControler.swift

**and here is my Code:**

Fragment of code of the Cell:

```
class MainTableCollectionViewCell: UITableViewCell{
var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirection.Horizontal
    self.collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRectZero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    self.collectionView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "MainTableCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: collectionViewCellIdentifier)
    self.collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    self.contentView.addSubview(self.collectionView)
}
// -----------somestuff like delegates passing and overriding layoutsubviews below - I didnt include it here, I can paste it if necessary-------------
```

Fragment of code of the controller (see my comments in dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier) :

```
class MainTableCollectionViewController: UITableViewController,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {

  // @IBOutlet var labelText: UILabel!

override init(){
    super.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    self.tableView.registerClass(MainTableCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: reuseTableViewCellIdentifier)

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
private override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 15
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseCollectionViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    //I would like to be able to put something like 
    // cell.label.text ="indexPath.row" but I need the outlet 
    // active

return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't connect a `UICollectionView` in a `UITableView` to your code. But why don't you use the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function to display your `indexPath.row`?

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseCollectionViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)

    return cell
}
```

And then you connect your UICollectionView datasource and delegate in the XIB.

Comment: i cannot do that cell.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)  This doesnt work, because i dont have the textLabel defined anywhere. This is my problem - I don't know how to define it. Tried putting @IBOutlet textLabel in my Cell controller - but i cannot link the outlet to the Label in XIB. Thats because the XIB with cell isnt connected to the CellController class in Identity inspector. AND! I cannot connect it there since my XIB is a CollectionCell and my cell class is  UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented the collection view inside the tableview
You have to put collection view inside the UITableviewCell custom class and register delegate and datasource of the collection view in UITableView custom class cell
I have implemented in the following repository
https://github.com/EonKid/CollectionViewInsideTableView